# A conversão implícita do tipo de dados nvarchar em varbinary(max) não é permitida. Use a função CONVERT para executar essa consulta

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-update

Segue código:

```
byte[] image1 = ConvertTo.Bytes(Request.Files[0]);
byte[] image2 = null;

ctx
.Users
.Where(x => x.Id == 1)
.Update(x => new User()
{
    ImageByte1 = image1,
    ImageByte2 = image2
});
```

Eu uso essa aqui: http://entityframework-plus.net/

Só da problema se eu definir `null` na `ImageByte2`. Segue erro:

> A conversão implícita do tipo de dados nvarchar em varbinary(max) não
>   é permitida. Use a função CONVERT para executar essa consulta

Agora seu eu definir `ImageByte1` e `ImageByte2` como `null`, faz update normalmente ou `ImageByte1` e `ImageByte2` diferente de `null` também faz update.

Alguma solução?

Comment: @LINQ, sim, são anuláveis

Comment: Esse já não aceita `SqlBinary.Null`  :/

Comment: @LINQ, problema já foi resolvido atualizando a versão mais recente `1.7.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema já foi corrigido com a versão mais atualizada.

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/